# I get error when trying to filter mongoose data using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to filter and paginate data from my API, but I keep getting an error. here is the code I am trying to use to achieve that.

```
router.get('/api/place', async (req, res) => {
    //  pagination and filter
    // const match = {}

    const noOnPage = parseInt(req.query.limit) || 10
    const pageNo = (parseInt(req.query.page)-1)*parseInt(req.query.limit)

    try {
        const place = await Place.find({
            isOpen: true
        })
        .populate({
            select: '-media',
            match,
            options: {
                limit: noOnPage,
                skip: pageNo
            }
        })
        .exec()

        console.log("hello");
        res.status(200).send(place)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send()
    }
})
```

please what could I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

remove `match` and set `path` argument with name of field that has `ref`

```
       const place = await Place.find({
            isOpen: true
        })
        .populate({
            path: 'user',
            select: '-media',
            options: {
                limit: noOnPage,
                skip: pageNo
            }
        })
```

Comment: but if i do that, i will not be getting a list of places that only that user has created but this route is for places all users on the app have created, also, the pagination doesn't work also

Comment: read the documentation of populate https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html, after that I don't know the schemas and between relation, user is a example, but every populate need to a path